# Change image on click then back to original image on another image click

Tags: jquery, image, click

I need some help changing an image on click then changing it back to the original image when another image is clicked. All I have so far is changing the image on the first click, but I don't know the next part, that it goes back to the original image when ANOTHER image is clicked. This is what I have:

```
$(function() {
    $('#two').click(function(){
        $("#imgtwo").attr('src',"resources/items/icon2blue.png"); 
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $('#two').click(function(){
        $('#imgtwo').data('targetsrc',$(this).attr('src'));
        $("#imgtwo").attr('src',"resources/items/icon2blue.png");
    });


    $('#imgtwo').click(function(){
        $("#two").attr('src',$(this).data('targetsrc'));
        $('#two').data('targetsrc',$(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
```

try this.set another attrib and get value from it

Comment: Assuming the element `$('#imgtwo')` is a `<img>`, `targetsrc` is not a valid attribute. This will break the W3C validation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img

Comment: I made some changes. try this

Answer (score 0):

When you click on any image, change the image and reset all other images back to their default image. That way, each time any given image is clicks, it will change and you know all others will be set back to default.

```
$('#one').click(function(){
    $("#imgone").attr('src',"resources/items/click-image.png");
    $("#imgtwo").attr('src',"resources/items/standard-image.png");
    $("#imgthree").attr('src',"resources/items/standard-image.png"); 
});
$('#two').click(function(){
    $("#imgone").attr('src',"resources/items/standard-image.png");
    $("#imgtwo").attr('src',"resources/items/click-image.png");
    $("#imgthree").attr('src',"resources/items/standard-image.png"); 
});
$('#three').click(function(){
    $("#imgone").attr('src',"resources/items/standard-image.png");
    $("#imgtwo").attr('src',"resources/items/standard-image.png");
    $("#imgthree").attr('src',"resources/items/click-image.png"); 
});
```

My JS is rusty but you get the idea.

Comment: Hi Scott, how do I do that? Sorry, but I am very new to jquery so am not familiar at all with the code. THanks :)

Comment: Updated and added some code, it may not be perfect but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgArray = [  
 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Brain_human_sagittal_section.svg/295px-Brain_human_sagittal_section.svg.png',
 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Solanum_muricatum_Flower_and_Fruit.jpg/220px-Solanum_muricatum_Flower_and_Fruit.jpg'
];

var counter = 0;
document.getElementById('my_button').onclick = function () {  
    document.getElementById('mainImage').src = imgArray[counter % imgArray.length]; 
    counter += 1;
}
```

Hope this will be helpful

try this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sornalingam/XyezG/

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery ? The original question is using jQuery.

Comment: Also, your `counter` will overflow by clicking 9,007,199,254,740,992 or more times, of course the mouse button will be broken before that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
$(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $('#two').click(function(){
        $("#imgtwo").attr('src',"resources/items/icon2blue.png"); 
    });
    $('#image2').click(function(){ // do it with other images
        if(count < 4) {
            count++;
        } else {
            // reset to original image
            count = 0;
            $("#imgtwo").attr('src',"resources/items/original_image.png"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Assuming another image has `id` of `another_image`.

Alternatively, you probably want to have a toggle image, which can be done as follow:

```
$(function() {
    var img_state = true;
    $('#two').click(function(){
        if(img_state) {
            $("#imgtwo").attr('src',"resources/items/icon2blue.png"); 
        } else {
            $("#imgtwo").attr('src',"resources/items/another_image.png"); 
        }
        img_state = !img_state;
    });
});
```

Comment: Shivan, I need the image to change back to the original when ANOTHER button is clicked, not the same one. I have 4 images, so if any three images are clicked, then the 4th one should revert back to the original image.

Comment: so, 1st part of solution suits your needs.

Comment: How do I identify more than one image then, that if clicked will change the 4th image? Because isn't '#another_image' identifying one other image, not the other three?